# readurl from XML document tree

Tags: xml, r, url

I like to get exact **Block FIPS** id from a datafile with particular latitude longitude (1200 rows).

```
Latitude    Longitude   ADT
30.0777     -92.43778   84
30.0788     -92.39427   216
30.07883    -92.39575   185
30.07952    -92.3781    88
30.08025    -92.50803   2025
30.08028    -92.36187   2715
```

By pulling [this API](http://www.fcc.gov/developers/census-block-conversions-api), I can manually get the Block Geoid2 like this:

```
<Response xmlns="http://data.fcc.gov/api" status="OK" executionTime="24">
<Block FIPS="220019612003034"/>
<County FIPS="22001" name="Acadia"/>
<State FIPS="22" code="LA" name="Louisiana"/>
</Response>
```

I create a new .csv with the urls for each data point (latitude, longitude):

```
a <- structure(list(Latitude = c("30.0777", "30.0788", "30.07883", "30.07952", "30.08025", "30.08028"), 
Longitude = c("-92.43778", "-92.39427", "-92.39575", "-92.3781", "-92.50803", "-92.36187"), 
url= c("http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.0777&longitude=-92.43778", "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.0788&longitude=-92.39427", 
"http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.07883&longitude=-92.39575", "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.07952&longitude=-92.3781", 
"http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.08025&longitude=-92.50803", "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.08028&longitude=-92.36187")),
.Names = c("Latitude", "Longitude", "url"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
a
Latitude    Longitude   url
30.0777     -92.43778   http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.0777&longitude=-92.43778
30.0788     -92.39427   http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.0788&longitude=-92.39427
30.07883    -92.39575   http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.07883&longitude=-92.39575
30.07952    -92.3781    http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.07952&longitude=-92.3781
30.08025    -92.50803   http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.08025&longitude=-92.50803
30.08028    -92.36187   http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=30.08028&longitude=-92.36187
```

First I tried to get one particular url info. But I am not getting the url info.

```
url <- "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=40.0&longitude=-85" 
readLines(url)
[1] "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Response xmlns=\"http://data.fcc.gov/api\" status=\"OK\" executionTime=\"10\"><Block FIPS=\"181770103002004\"/><County FIPS=\"18177\" name=\"Wayne\"/><State FIPS=\"18\" code=\"IN\" name=\"Indiana\"/></Response>"
Warning message:
In readLines(url) :
  incomplete final line found on 'http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=40.0&longitude=-85'
```

Finally I want final my table like this.

```
Latitude    Longitude   ADT      Block_FIPS
30.0777     -92.43778   84       220019603002020
30.0788     -92.39427   216      220019604002099
30.07883    -92.39575   185      220019603003019
30.07952    -92.3781    88       220019602002049
30.08025    -92.50803   2025     220019602003017
30.08028    -92.36187   2715     220019602003062
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried using the XML package?

Here's a way to extract your quantity of interest using this package:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=40.0&longitude=-85" 
api.call <- xmlInternalTreeParse(url)

xmlAttrs(xmlRoot(api.call)[[1]])
```

Depending on how much data you have, you may either just loop over all URLs and append the extracted data to your data set or write a little function that avoids R's slowness concerning loops.

**Update:**

Here's a quick example how to wrap my code above in a loop in order to extract the FIPS code for all rows in your data set.

```
a$FIPS <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    api.call <- xmlInternalTreeParse(a$url[i])
    a$FIPS[i] <- return(xmlAttrs(xmlRoot(api.call)[[1]]))
}
```

Here's the very same thing as a function (that takes one single URL value as an input):

```
get.fips <- function(url) {
api.call <- xmlInternalTreeParse(url)
return(xmlAttrs(xmlRoot(api.call)[[1]]))
}
# example: get.fips(a$url[1])
```

Comment: Trying to run the function. But ends up with an error message. Error in api.call[k] <- xmlInternalTreeParse(t[k]) : 
  object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable

Comment: @user2530371 sorry, but i cannot replicate your error. How did you adjust my code for the function?
In case you edited the last line and replaced the `[[1]]` with some variable: The `[[1]]` is supposed to stay the same since it indicates to extract the attributes of the first child element of the XML document (i.e. `<Block FIPS="220019612003034"/>`)

Comment: @user2530371 i just edited my answer and wrapped my original code inside a loop and a function. If you don't have thousands of rows, the loop will be sufficiently fast. Does it work for you?

Comment: How does your loop exactly look like? And have you started testing only the first iteration or try to run the whole loop?
For debugging advice, please post your complete code. The error snippet in your previous comment says that you want to save the API response in the `k`-th position of `api.call`. This is different from my example in which i overwrite `api.call` (i.e. the api response in XML format) in every iteration. Have you considered that?